# Параллельная обработка с GNU Parallel для foreach

Tags: циклы, распараллеливание, gnu

Здравствуйте,

Я новичок с GNU Parallel и буду рад если укажите на ошибки и некоторые недопонимания. Я прочел мануал но там говорится в основном про одноэтапные действие в которых нужно указать определенное "действие" в синтаксисе GNU Parallel (распаковка, перемещение) и ничего не указано про многоэтапные шаги, когда нужно выполнить несколько действий не меняя (существенно) при этом кода (если конечно такое вообще возможно)

Возможно ли реализовать  параллельную обработку, в коде, который ее по факту не поддерживает. Но в нем есть loop. То есть, имеются входящий список файлов в любом формате и в определенный момент в коде доходит дело до петли. (пример кода: 138 строчка [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/projects/gmt5sar/repository/entry/branches/5.2_KF/gmtsar/csh/intf_tops.csh))

Короче говоря возможно ли подобие параллельной обработки (**не изменяя при этом кода** существенно или только около 138 строчки), когда просто каждый файл одновременно начинает обрабатываться независимо от того какие действия прописаны в этом моменте в коде? (и даже **многоэтапные действия**, то есть когда например нужно добавить файл в архив и потом переместить и потом что-то еще и т.д.)

```
# Любые действия и обязательно "открытие или проверка наличия" списка файлов
# loop
#
  foreach line (`awk '{print $0}' $1`)
# Любые действия
```

Может быть это можно реализовать используя другой инструмент помимо GNU Parallel? Буду рад любой помощи! Спасибо заранее

Comment: сделайте функцию из тела цикла, и вызывайте её программой *parallel*.

Comment: Не могли бы чуть более подробнее (новчиок же) и лучше конечно пример синтаксиса. Пример кода который я кинул вызывается так `intf_tops.csh intf.in batch_tops.config` и совершенно не понятно как вызывать его например с GNU Parallel. И нужно чтобы именно этот момент который дан наверху начиная со 138 "разделялся". Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: Да и если сделать параллельным весь код то это вероятно может вызвать проблемы. Нужно именно в момент петли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### короткий ответ:

**малыми** изменениями в вашем случае распараллеливания (по крайней мере программой *gnu/parallel*) не добиться.

#### длинный ответ:

если бы использовался интерпретатор *bash*, то конструкцию на языке интерпретатора *csh*:

```
foreach line (`команда с аргументами`)
  какие-то команды
end
```

звучащую на языке интерпретатора *bash* так:

```
for line in `команда с аргументами`
  какие-то команды
done
```

можно было бы распараллелить примерно так:

```
fff() {
  какие-то команды
}
export -f fff
parallel line={} fff ::: `команда с аргументами`
```

но это сработало бы только в том случае, если бы внутри тела цикла не использовались переменные, определённые **до** начала цикла в этом же скрипте.

потому что программа `gnu/parallel` запустит новые процессы, которые не будут «знать» об этих локальных переменных.

---

следующий момент — в вашем примере используется интерпретатор *csh*, у которого нет поддержки функций:

> [Missing features most commonly cited are the lack of ability to manipulate the stdio file handles independently and **support for functions**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell#Criticism)

т.е. весь код из цикла, для возможности его вызова программой *gnu/parallel*, надо выносить в отдельный файл.

Comment: То есть по сути вынос в отдельный файл этого, момента решит проблему? Вы описали что надо сделать при bash, при csh проще переписать все я так понял?

Comment: @user2899758, я же, вроде, написал в ответе: функций у *csh* нет, поэтому команды, содержащийся **внутри** цикла, надо будет выносить в отдельный файл. и его уже и вызывать программой *parallel*, вставленной вместо **всего** цикла. если внутри цикла не используются переменные, описанные до цикла, то должно заработать.

Comment: @user2899758, я дополнил ответ конструкцией на *csh*, аналогичной конструкции на *bash*. и `export` в случае *csh*, понятно, не будет нужен.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все понятно.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать как я бы мог внести переменные в петлю? Или я могу добавить их в отдельный файл (который оговаривался выше) **перед петлей**? Или надо именно в ней указывать?

Comment: @user2899758, например, можете воспользоваться `setenv`, внутренней командой *csh* (аналогом `export`, внутренней команды *sh*).

Comment: setenv: Too many arguments. Не могли показать как правильно преобразовать из `set` в `setenv` на примере: `set dec = 'grep dec_factor $2 | awk '{print $3}''` (внутри вместо `'` запятая вверху) . И правильна ли подобная команда если я хочу чтобы каждый файл (их 15 например) (без распилки и тому подобное) обрабатывался `awk '{print $0}' $1 | parallel loop.csh` 
endif` И вверху в вашем примере `fff` это просто аргумент или метод распараллеливания? Спасибо большое, очень сильно помогли csh нов для меня в отличии от других языков

Comment: `fff` в примере — это команда, которую выполнит *gnu/parallel*. по поводу тонкостей работы *csh* — задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос по поводу GNU Parallel. Я попробовал сделать так как наверху но столкнулся c проблемой. Как внести внутренний файл (csh) в GNU Parallel? Также очень важно чтобы GNU Parallel осуществлял параллельную обработку ( по строкам `awk '{print $0}' $1`) по файлу `data.in` (код вверху). Иными словами он должен быть последовательным во внутреннем коде но запустить его (код) несколько раз одновременно для обработки файлов указанных в `data.in` Спасибо вам еще раз!

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.